# Rodrigues Rotation Formula Initial Derivation Step

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading from a textbook the derivation of Rodrigue's rotation formula and I'm wondering why the picture accompanying the derivation looks like this:[image]

The book initially starts off by explaining that v_parallel is the projection of v onto axis n, so shouldn't v_parallel look like the red arrow?

[image]

They also have the formula for v_parallel, which shows that it is a scalar of n.

Comment: You are right. What is that you do not understand? $v_{||}$ is a free vector. You can represent it using any representative, like the one in the picture.

Comment: In other words: $\boldsymbol{v}=\boldsymbol{v}_{\|}+\boldsymbol{v}_\bot$ - as we know. In that vector addition it does not matter if you visualize $\boldsymbol{v}_{\|}$ as the red vector, or as the one whose foot is at the tip of $\boldsymbol{v}_{\bot}\,.$

Comment: Oh, ok, it's been a while since I've done vector analysis, so I thought vectors were unique in both direction and position.